# my programming language C#

Tags: c#

```html
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Program.keepRunnig = true;
            this.Close();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(@"E:\NabilDataBase\ChangeFormLang\ChangeFormLang\1.txt");
            switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag)
            {
                case "en-US": Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-IQ");

               //     stw.Write("ar-IQ");
            stw.Close();
                    break;
                case "ar-AR": Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                    
       //     stw.Write("en-US");
            stw.Close();
                    break;
            }
            
            this.Controls.Clear();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

I made a program multi language interface with thread class and added two language,my question is when I change the interface to another language that I added and close the form then I reopen it I see the interface returned to the default language, how can I save it the interface when closed.[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Copy paste the actual code, not an image.

Comment: First questions are reviewed by the community no?

Answer (score 4):

If you [create a new Setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8(v=vs.100).aspx) "Culture" you can save information at runtime like so:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Culture= "ar-ar";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

And load it like so:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.Culture);
```

[How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thank you for your effort but I cannot get the (Properties.Settings.Default.Culture)

Comment: You have to add a Culture Setting before you can do that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: after adding your code it didn't change the language how can I send you my code to help me.

Comment: You could just copy and paste the important areas into your question above.

Comment: this.Controls.Clear();
            InitializeComponent();

Comment: is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes there should be a solution for your problem but nobody wants to help you until you edit your question to a readable code example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you for your advice , I added my code please now if you can to help me only I want to save on the interface that I close it